# Fractional Laplacian definition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Recently I have been working with the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{s} $ where $s\in(0,1)$. Generally I understand its definition, but what stills confuses me is the purpose of the negative symbol. Why is the fractional Laplacian defined as above and not simply as $(\Delta)^{s}$?
Any answer would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Because $-\Delta$ is a positive operator (in a suitable) sense, so that taking arbitrary powers is possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: Compare this to diagonalizable matrices: we can define arbitrary powers of symmetric positive definite matrices through eigenvalue decomposition. The same can be done for the negative Laplacian.